# Reading from stdout

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using ssh-exec npm and I want to get the the result of a remote ssh command, parse it, and store it into an array. It's being piped to stdout instead, and I'm not sure how to get it into a variable.

```
function GetRemoteLinuxIp(hostAddress) {
  console.log(hostAddress);

  exec("ifconfig -a | tr -s ' ' | awk -F'[: ]' '  {if (/^[a-z]/) printf $1 \" \"}  {if (/inet addr:/) print $4 }' ", {
    user: 'user',
    host: hostAddress,
    password: 'password'
  }).pipe(process.stdout)
};
```

the output is

```
enp0s3 192.168.1.8
enp0s3 192.168.1.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this, if you don't want to use pipes. It's still going to be asynchronous, so you'll have to at least use something like a callback or promise if you're looking to return this data from the function.

```
exec("ifconfig -a | tr -s ' ' | awk -F'[: ]' '  {if (/^[a-z]/) printf $1 \" \"}  {if (/inet addr:/) print $4 }' ", {
    user: 'user',
    host: hostAddress,
    password: 'password'
}).on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('data:', data);
  // parse and push items onto an array
}).on('end', function() {
  // no more data will be coming in
  // resolve your promise with the array,
  // or pass it in to your callback from here
});
```

You want to take a look at the [streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) interface, specifically the readable one.